# Unable to fetch the textarea text

Tags: jquery

On click of a button i am trying to fetch the text comments of a textArea .

I tried this way

```
<textarea class="sometextareas" placeholder="Write Comments"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Fetch Comments" class="mybutton" />


$(document).on('click', '.mybutton', function (e) {

    var tester = $('.sometextareas').text();

    alert(tester);


});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/47/

could you please let me whats the issue .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `text()` to `val()` to get comments from `textarea`.

```
var tester = $('.sometextareas').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/48/)**

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` is used to get the text(not Html) from any html element. And `.val()` is used to get the value of input elements. So you have to use `.val()` here instead of `.text()`.